# How to fling the sprite in the direction of a swipe SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, uipangesturerecognizer

So I figured out how to move my sprite up down left and right with swipes, but I was wondering if there was a way for the sprite to be flung in any direction depending on the swipe direction of the user.  How can one do this in SpriteKit

Comment: Please post the code that you have implemented at the moment

Answer (score 0):

use `func applyImpulse(_ impulse: CGVector)` from `SKPhysicsBody`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/making_physics_bodies_move